# Dijkstra's alghoritm second minimum way

Tags: algorithm, graph, theory, dijkstra

So i have next task:find minimum and second minimum way(which can be same) value in graph and for that i use Dijkstra's alghoritm. With first minimum everything good(just use alghoritm) but i have problem with finding second minimum.Tried to find another way ,based on first minimum way, with smallest difference but that's isn't always working because second minimum way can be different from first.So any ideas on finding second minimum way?

Comment: We don't do assignment here. SO is Q&A site for coding problem. Please show us what you tried so far. Also have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Code: http://pastebin.com/4vkGKX4Y.problem line  45.It finds only one value corresponding to each verticles, but i need two.Tried to fix it using if() but that isn't working.Tried to change mindistance function but its sometimes works , sometimes not(wasn't working correctly when minimum graph was like 1-3-5-8 while 5 and 8 wasn't adjacent)

Comment: You could try this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen's_algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you store the distance in an array like `distance[x]` representing the distance to the node `x`, you can switch the array to a `matrix`. So, for every node `x` you'll have a list of values stored in `distance[x]`. From now on, use all of this values to compute the distances to all node adjacent with `x`. After everything is finished, you can select the line for your destination node and pick the second minimum value from there.